# YiiBooster TbButtonGroup inside TbExtendedGridView is partially invisible

Tags: gridview, twitter-bootstrap, yii, buttongroup

I use Yii with YiiBooster extension. I'm trying to add a TbButtonGroup (so I have nice dropdown style menu with some actions) to a TbExtendedGridView widget. It is placed inside the very last column of the grid view and when I click to open a dropdown menu - the menu is only partially visible. Part of the menu that exceeds the TbExtendedGridView rectangle is not visible. How to make it be totally visible?
My code is following:

```
array(
        'header' => '',
        'value' => function($data)
        {
            $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonGroup', array(
                    'size'=>'mini',
                    'type'=>'inverse', 
                    'buttons'=>array(
                        array('icon'=>'align-left', 'type'=>'', 'items'=>array
                        (
                            array('label'=>'Statystyki liczbowe', 'url'=>'#'),
                            array('label'=>'Statystyki liczbowe', 'url'=>'#'),
                            array('label'=>'Statystyki liczbowe', 'url'=>'#'),
                            array('label'=>'Statystyki liczbowe', 'url'=>'#'),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ));
        }
    ),
```

Comment: works fine for me. seems that you have problem in css

Comment: Hm you're right. I noticed it is being cut by the right column (it is default 2-column yii boilerplate layout). That is interesting because `z-index` for the popover is set to 1000. I'm inspecting this further maybe I'll find sth.

Answer (score 2):

`$this` will not work in `function($data)`

What you should try, is something like this:

```
Yii::app()->controller->widget
```